# Spring cache, force to set the return type

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching, spring-cache

I'm trying to implement `org.springframework.cache.Cache`
The cached value is stored as JSON in a SQL database.
In the Cache interface, there are multiple get methods.

```
ValueWrapper get(Object key);
<T> T get(Object key, @Nullable Class<T> type);
<T> T get(Object key, Callable<T> valueLoader);
```

This is the first one that is used (without type or any generic information).
The problem is that since I save the value as JSON, I'd like to have the return value of the cached methods to help deserialize it.

How can I force spring to use the method `<T> T get(Object key, @Nullable Class<T> type);` when using the @Cacheable annotation ?

My cache implementation (kotlin) :

```
class SqlCache(
    private val name: String,
    private val expiration: Duration,
    private val cacheRepository: CacheRepository,
): Cache {

    private val isoObjectMapper = ObjectMapper()
        .registerModule(KotlinModule())
        .registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
        .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
        .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)

    override fun getName(): String {
        return name
    }

    override fun getNativeCache(): Any {
        return cacheRepository
    }

    // The method called by spring !
    override fun get(key: Any): Cache.ValueWrapper? {
        val cache = cacheRepository.find(name = name, key = key.toString()) ?: return null
        val value = isoObjectMapper.readValue(cache.value, UserModel::class)
        return SimpleValueWrapper(value)
    }

    override fun <T : Any?> get(key: Any, type: Class<T>?): T? {
        val cache = cacheRepository.find(name = name, key = key.toString()) ?: return null
        return isoObjectMapper.readValue(cache.value, type)
    }

    override fun <T : Any?> get(key: Any, valueLoader: Callable<T>): T? {
        return null
    }

    override fun put(key: Any, value: Any?) {
        cacheRepository.put(
            name = name,
            key = key.toString(),
            value = value,
            expiration = expiration,
        )
    }

    override fun evict(key: Any) {
        cacheRepository.delete(
            name = name,
            key = key.toString(),
        )
    }

    override fun clear() {
    }
}
```

Exemple of cache usage :

```
interface UserClientAdapter {
    @Cacheable(value = ["user-cache"], key = "#id")
    fun getUser(id: UUID): UserModel
}
```

So, in this last method, the user is well stored as a JSON string in the database.
But when we try to get back the cache. This is the method `ValueWrapper get(Object key);` that is called. So I don't know the expected return type of the method.

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to the `RedisCache` implementation class.
extends `AbstractValueAdaptingCache`
Implement the `lookup` method
Write your deserialization method in the `lookup` method

```
protected Object lookup(Object key) {
    byte[] value = this.cacheWriter.get(this.name, this.createAndConvertCacheKey(key));
    return value == null ? null : this.deserializeCacheValue(value);
}
```

If you still can't return your results

Then you need to debug `CacheAspectSupport.java` `execute` method,

which handles the hit `Cache.ValueWrapper`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But I want to use the @Cacheable annotation.

Comment: @Cacheable It will be deserialized automatically

Comment: It is not working. Reason why I opened the ticket.

Comment: If your method returns a string？

Comment: No, the method don't returns a string.
But it is saved as a JSON string in the database.

Comment: Is there any sample code? I still don't understand the problem. Normally the cache serializes when it's saved, deserializes when it's hit, and it's all automatic

Comment: Ok, I added some details on my original question.

Comment: Does this solve your problem ?

Comment: Actually no, because I still don't have information about the target type, so I can't deserialize given the method's return type :-/

Comment: `val value = isoObjectMapper.readValue(cache.value, UserModel::class)` Whether this line failed to deserialize

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want that. Spring knows the return type of the method. And on the Cache interface there are methods that indicates that it is possible to get the target type. I don't want to couple my SqlCache to a model class.

Comment: You should refer to the `redisCache` implementation instead

When serialized, he stores the return type of the method into json